# Instock and out of stock issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, stock

Please help me to find out issue,I am using Magento 2.1.8 with custom porto theme. When change product stock status to outofstock it's not display in frontend.

In frontend product page there always show instock product label even I change status from admin.

but ,When i run reindex data command and it's working perfect. So how we solve this issue.
why i have every time run reindec command ?

Comment: Please set cron job in your webstore. It will reindex your store after some regular intervals.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to select action "update on save" from index management.

Go to **System->Tools->Index Management**

Now select checkbox of indexer **Stock** and select **Update On Save** from action dropdown.

Now any stock update immediately affected at the time of saving product. Do not need to run indexer every time.